# Is there a way to make the background clear of anything and leave only the biggest contour after applying adaptive threshold

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

This is the full code I'm using and I've included the output images. I'm trying to remove the background and then apply contour to it so that the only item left is the outline of the plane. I've attached the images from the code after applying threshold and contouring

[After Threshold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpeXj.jpg)

[After Contouring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcMuJ.png)

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import argparse

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--input", required=True,
    help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=True,
    help="path to output image")

args = vars(ap.parse_args())

src = cv2.imread(args["input"], 1) # read input image

gray = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # convert to grayscale

blur = cv2.blur(gray, (3, 3)) # blur the image

# Otsu's thresholding
th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
thresh = cv2.resize(th2, (1080 , 480))
cv2.imshow("thresh",thresh)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# create hull array for convex hull points
hull = []

# calculate points for each contour
for i in range(len(contours)):
    # creating convex hull object for each contour
    hull.append(cv2.convexHull(contours[i], False))
# create an empty black image
drawing = np.zeros((thresh.shape[0], thresh.shape[1], 3), np.uint8)

# draw contours and hull points
for i in range(len(contours)):
    color_contours = (0, 255, 0) # green - color for contours
    color = (255, 0, 0) # blue - color for convex hull
    # draw ith contour
    cv2.drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color_contours, 1, 8, hierarchy)
    # draw ith convex hull object

drawing = cv2.resize(drawing, (1080 , 480))
cv2.imshow(args["output"], drawing)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Filter your contours by area so that you only keep the largest one. The you can draw the contour filled with the input image or any color on a black background of the same size as the input, if that is what you want. See cv2.contourArea(). I would also suggest you use morphology after thresholding to clean up the smaller regions.

Comment: @fmw42 yes that's what I'm looking for but I'm unsure how to implement cv2.contourArea() in my code

Comment: Negate your thresholded image first so you white outlines on black background. Does that work.

Comment: @fmw42 yup, now it works thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of filtering on area to get the largest contour:

```
# get outer contours and filter to get the largest (presumably only one)
cntrs = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cntrs = cntrs[0] if len(cntrs) == 2 else cntrs[1]
# create black background image
result = np.zeros_like(src)
area_thresh = 0
for c in cntrs:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > area_thresh:
        area_thresh = area
        big_contour = c

# draw largest contour on black background
cv2.drawContours(result, [big_contour], -1, (0,0,255), 1)
```

Comment: Thanks this looks good! Just one thing I noticed, the biggest contour it found is the entire image and not the plane outline.

Comment: Hi! I could use your help with this code again, supposing there are more than 1 largest contours, say 2 or 3. What would i need to change to find more than 1?

Comment: Just draw all contours that are larger than some threshold.

Comment: I apologize, I'm not totally clear on what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep more than one contour, you can simply keep any that are larger than some threshold in Python OpenCV. Here is the previous code modified to do that for a minimum area of 10000. All contours larger than 10000 will be drawn.

```
# get outer contours and filter to get the largest (presumably only one)
cntrs = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cntrs = cntrs[0] if len(cntrs) == 2 else cntrs[1]
# create black background image
result = np.zeros_like(src)
area_thresh = 10000
for c in cntrs:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > area_thresh:
        cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (0,0,255), 1)
```